# browser drivers automatic download by gradle build

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

Hi I am new to gradle project. I have configured selenium with gradle. I have to test my selenium code in different browsers. Is it possible to download required browser drivers by gradle import, if so what dependencies I have to use in gradle.build. At present I am using the below, but I am not getting the required result.

```
configurations {
    drivers
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.+'
    compile(group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.1.+'){ exclude group: "junit" }

    drivers ("com.company:chromedriver-win32:2.8@exe",
            "com.company:iechromedriver-win32:2.39@exe")
}

task copyDrivers(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.drivers
    into "$buildDir/drivers-down"
}
```

Comment: Can you refine your question, please? and tell us what is wrong.

Comment: I need to download all browser drivers during my gradle import and use it by calling required driver in my test cases. Don't look at the above code, it may be wrong.

Comment: This might helps you https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager